# Typescript: Define generic functions in inner functions of a interface/ type without defining types at top interface level?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
type MyFunc<T> = (functionParamm: T )=> void;
type Foo = {
    func1?<T>:  MyFunc<T> // is there a way to define my type parameter only here and not for the whole containig type?
}
```

I can do something like

```
type MyFunc<T> = (functionParamm: T )=> void;
type Foo<T=any> = {
    func1?:  MyFunc<T> 
}
```

But this becomes impractical if I have a lot of generic functions defined inside.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wgvE4W) work for you? If yes I will write up the answer with an explanation; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: It doesn't actually work since I still don't get to define an implementation on Foo func1.
[here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgYwDwBUB8UC8UAFAGYqrACWA9sgAoCGATvQLYBcUmAlPrgG5UKAEwDcAKFCQo8KlXxQA3mKhRSaAIwB+DlmyEAdIaYBzAM4cGzFhGARGp9HCRpd2HnlwAlG4kbJM4BCOCGSu4gC+4mKoNKbAUABGHDJyBApqqOpshOZxjBTIxlweCjHIplQANhD6lVTGOVzhkWJiCfoZWvqE6gBMXCJQAPRDUMiILAl2bR1kXYQA5PSmQgsDw6N5BcYznZrdANoLCwC66yNQW4UHJ0A)